# how to restrict content in wordpress

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, wordpress

I have a wordpress website and I want to add facebook restriction on page and post. After adding the same visitor need to join a facebook group to view post/page content (unlock).Is there any way to do so?

I want show some content for my fb group members only or verify the visitor  whether he/she is member of the concern group or not. if yes show the content. Group members 90,000 plus.

I have found some plugins, but all of having like button
e.g "Social Locker for Wordpress".
ref - http://codecanyon.net/item/social-locker-for-wordpress/3667715?.

I have googled but couldn't find anything useful.

Comment: Only if the group has less then 5000 people. Then just use user_managed_groups permission and call /groupid/members and you will get all memebers

Comment: my group having 90,000 plus members

Comment: Then it is not possible

Comment: I want show some content for my fb group members only in a wordpress website. can you give me any idea abut the same.?

Comment: It is not possible